# Diff-in-Diff with a small N (N=20) and a small number of treated units (2 or 1), but with large T (T=80). What are the main problems?

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference

What are the main problems one may have when estimating a diff-in-diff model with small N (N=20), small number of treated units (2 units) and a large T (T=80)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [very nice paper](http://michael-lechner.eu/pdf/journals/99_Lechner_DiD_2011_ECO%200403%20Lechner_darf%20aufs%20Netz.pdf) by Michael Lechner on DiD, which gets into some of this (see Section 6 on page 210). He writes:

> There may be a problem for identification, estimation, and inference
>   (see previous section) if, for example, one region is subject to a
>   treatment in period $t$ (i.e., all units are subject to the new
>   regime), whereas couple of other regions are not subject to it.

He recommends the synthetic cohort methods for the case with few treated units.

The large number of periods can be useful, but only if the common trends assumption holds. Synthetic cohorts can relax this one as well.